# access values of one2many fields on kanban view odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, qweb, one2many

Why i can't access values of one2many field on kanabn view . i need to loop over them to access them but it only return the number of records that's it.
 I have tried this code but it is'nt working

```
<kanban>
<field name="one2manyFieldname"/>
<templates>
    <t t-name="kanban-box">
        <div class="oe_kanban_content">
            <p>
               <t t-foreach="record.one2manyFieldname.raw_value" t-as='o'>
                   <t t-esc="o.name"/><field name="name"/><br/>
               </t>
            </p>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

instead of getting values i am getting blank result.Kindly help on this problem.Thank You

Comment: This issue was solved with the above code only.only thing i did was removed the field name="name" and arranged these things in table

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this too. What did you mean by 'arranged these things in table'. Can you please tell me? I am getting blank results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can also set the customized module from the odoo addons

You can install and use it as per your Odoo version

**One2many Field Developed By SerpentCS :**

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_one2many_kanban/

Comment: Thanx @Dasadiya ...using this module only I solved the issue and after installing it I had iterated one2many field in kanban view to get the appropriate result